# Django queryset with Q gives wrong length

Tags: django

I'm struggling with or query. It give me weird output.
In models file i have as shown below:

```
class Server:
  addres_ip=models.GenericIPAddressField()

class Interface:
  addres_ip=models.CharField(max_length=15,default='127.0.0.1',blank=True)
  server=models.ForeignKey(Server,default=None,blank=True,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In db i have added a Server object with addres_ip='10.0.10.11' and with his Interface with addres_ip='10.1.1.2'.

When i query:
`Server.objects.filter(addres_ip='10.0.10.11')` I get 1 result and it's correct
`Interface.objects.filter(addres_ip='10.0.10.11')` I get 0 results and it's correct as well

but when I query:

`Server.objects.filter(Q(adress_ip='10.0.10.11') | Q(Interface__adress_ip='10.0.10.11'))` i get 7 results........

Am i missing something ? there should be 1 result ..I think but not sure right now ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 7 instances of `Interface` having a foreign key to the `Server` having `addres_ip='10.0.10.11'` hence from the join (performed due to writing `Interface__adress_ip='10.0.10.11'`) you get 7 (duplicated) objects / rows in the result.

Add a `.distinct()` at the end of your query, to remove the duplicate results:

```
Server.objects.filter(Q(adress_ip='10.0.10.11') | Q(Interface__adress_ip='10.0.10.11')).distinct()
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought i was going crazy - you saved my day. Thanks a lot.